# How to transfer DATE_ATOM to unix time?

Tags: php, datetime

some time format like: `Sat, 19 Feb 2011 09:02:04 -0800`,
How to transfer the DATE_ATOM to unix time(a ten digits numbers)? thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$timestamp = strtotime('Sat, 19 Feb 2011 09:02:04 -0800');
```

http://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php

http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php

Answer (score 2):

Try this
`strtotime('Sat, 19 Feb 2011 09:02:04 -0800');`